# Looping over lists and using its elements as parameters to invoke macros

Tags: pgffor

I'm trying to automatize the generation of certificates of participation for an event. I'm trying to have LaTeX iterate over a list of pairs of the form {author, talk} using `pgffor` like in the snippet below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\Talks{
  {John Doe, Very Cool Work on Stuff},
  {Jane Doe, Cooler Work on other Stuff}%
}

\newcommand{\Show}[2]{
\newpage
#1 presented the talk titled #2
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in \Talks
{
   % How to send the parameters do \Show?
   \Show{?}{?}
}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost works without change. The preferred seperator when using [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fforpg) is a slash, so you are better off using

```
\def\Talks{
      John Doe/Very Cool Work on Stuff,
      Jane Doe/Cooler Work on other Stuff%
 }
```

Once you have this you can use

```
\foreach \author/\talk in \Talks
    {
       % How to send the parameters do \Show?
       \Show{\author}{\talk}
    }
```

to loop over the talks to produce:

[image]
[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\Talks{
  John Doe/Very Cool Work on Stuff,
  Jane Doe/Cooler Work on other Stuff%
}

\newcommand{\Show}[2]{
\newpage
#1 presented the talk titled #2
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \author/\talk in \Talks
{
   % How to send the parameters do \Show?
   \Show{\author}{\talk}
}
\end{document}
```

This said, I'd probably do this using something like

```
\newcommand{\ShowTalks}{
    \foreach \author/\talk in \Talks
    {
        \newpage
        \author\space presented the talk titled \talk
    }
}
```